# Default values of attributes in Restful web service

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm using Spring Restful web service using Java 1.7

I've a json mapper class which has getter / setter methods for fName, lName, address, currentTime, etc

Now, this class has below attribute:

```
@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT)
```

Because of this attribute, my rest web service does not return attributes which have default values.

What needs to be done to retain these values?

If I set the Inclusion to NON_NULL, it works but then it gives problem in heartbeat API where I need only currentTime.

I've getter/setter for currentTime in same jason mapper class & this returns all other attributes with default values if I set the inclusion to NON_NULL.

How do I handle this in RESTFul services? I just want time attribute to be returned for heartbeat API & for other APIs, I need all attributes along with default values.

I'll appreciate if any one can give suggestions!!

UPDATE: Here is my code:

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "heartbeat", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes="application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> getHeartBeat() throws Exception {
    String curr_time = myService.getCurrentTime();      
    return MyServiceUtil.getResponse(curr_time, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "info", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> getData(@RequestBody String body) throws Exception {
    ....
    myInfo = myService.getMyInfo(myServiceJson);
    return MyServiceUtil.getResponse(myInfo, responseHeader, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

MyService.java

```
@Override
public String getCurrentTime() throws Exception {
    String currentDateTime = null;
    MyServiceJson json = new MyServiceJson();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {           
        Date currDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        currentDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(currDate);           
        json.setCurrentDateTime(currentDateTime);

        ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writerWithView(Views.HeartBeatAPI.class);
        return writer.writeValueAsString(json);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Excpetion in getCurrentTime: ", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);           
    }
}

@Override
public String getMyInfo(MyServiceJson myServiceJson) throws Exception {             
    MyServiceJson json = new MyServiceJson();
    json.setFirstName("hhh");
    json.setLastName("abc");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(json);
}
```

Views.java

```
public class Views {
    public static class HeartBeatAPI {  }
}
```

MyServiceJson.java

```
@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class MyServiceJson {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;   
    private String lastName;

    @JsonView(Views.HeartBeatAPI.class) 
    private String currentDateTime;

    // Getter/Setter for the above variables here
    .....

}
```

When I run heartbeat API, I'm still getting id value as 0 which is default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using either a @JsonFilter or @JsonView.

#### Using JsonFilter

```
@JsonFilter("myBeanFilter")
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    private String fName;
    private lName;
    private address;
    private Date currentTime;

    // Constructors, Getters/Setters
}

final MyBean bean = new MyBean();
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("myBeanFilter",
    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("currentTime"));
final String json = mapper.filteredWriter(filters).writeValueAsString(value);
```

#### Using JsonView

```
public class Views {
    static class HeartbeatAPI { }
}

public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    private String fName;
    private lName;
    private address;

    @JsonView(Views.HeartbeatAPI.class)
    private Date currentTime;

    // Constructors, Getters/Setters
}

final MyBean bean = new MyBean();
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(
    SerializationConfig.Feature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);;
final ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writerWithView(Views.HeartbeatAPI.class);
final String json = writer.writeValueAsString(bean);
```

Both of these methods ***do*** require that you have control of the serialization process, via an `ObjectMapper`.

- [JsonFilter Guide](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter)
- [JsonView Guide](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews)

Comment: Which one is preferred? Using JsonView looks better, with JsonView, do I need to include all my APIs within Views class? in the json mapper file? Also, does it need to be static?

Comment: It depends on how heavily you want to annotate your classes really. JsonFilters require fewer annotations than JsonViews in most cases. However, you are only masking one property, so it will really be up to what you feel most comfortable with. Your 'view' class is literally just used to tag the properties in your bean into groups. It doesn't require anything more than what I showed in my example.

Comment: I don't see writeValueUsingView method in objectmapper. I'm using Jackson version 1.9.9 & objectmapper is from org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper

Comment: Last line in my example shouldn't have been there. You can safely remove it (see edit)

Comment: I'm still not clear. The example that you gave is for heartbeat, right? How do I take care for other API where I need all attributes? One important issue is that my view is defined in MyServiceJson.java which has Json getter/setter...The objectmapper is present in some other file. How can I access View in othre file?

Comment: Do I need to create separate file for public class Views {
    static class HeartbeatAPI { }
}   And where do I need to provide implementation for  HeartbeatAPI ?

Comment: Yes, create another (source) file for the Views. You were already successfully handling the case where you serialize all attribute right? Using Views won't impact that.

Comment: ok..I'll create Views.java and include HeartBeatAPI class in it...but where is the actual implementation go for this API? Do I need to provide in the same Views.java within the HeartBeatAPI class?

Comment: Create the Views class exactly as I showed, the HeartbeatAPI class is just a tag (empty implementation)

Comment: I did that but I'm still getting other values...What should I set for @JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL) I've set it to NON_NULL & its giving me all

Comment: Evidently, there is an additional configuration needed on the mapper to avoid other properties from being written out when using views. See edit to my answer (tested, should work for you).

Comment: Can we do this config via annotation? Also, I don't see any SerializationConfig class. Which package does it exist?

Comment: Its a simple change, in your `getCurrentTime` method, change `new ObjectMapper()` to `new ObjectMapper().configure(
    SerializationConfig.Feature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);`